# Javascript React Conditional For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I need to populate an array with products, but every fourth product I need to add a Div.
Syntactically speaking, what's the best way to use the map, filter, reduce scheme to achieve this?

Something like this (pseudocode)

```js
myList.map((item, key) => {
    if(key % 4 == 0){
      <div>
        {item}
      </div>
    } else {
        {item}
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That'd work. You just have to `return` from the `map`.

```
 myList.map((item, key) => {
    if(key % 4 == 0){
      return (<div>
        {item}
      </div>)
    } else {
       return {item}
    }
})
```

Also, there's a typo I guess at the end. It should be closing with `)` instead of `}`

Comment: This will not work `myList.map((item, key) => return {` as it will through error such as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myList.map((item, index) => ((index + 1) % 4) === 0 ? <div>{item}</div> : item)
```

You have to use `index + 1` because the value of `index` starts from 0, so for the first fourth element the index would be 3 and `index + 1` makes it 4(which satisfies the condition `(index + 1) % 4) === 0`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this- https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-colden-4m2w3?file=/src/App.js

```
{myList.map((item, key) => {
    if (key % 2 === 0) {
      return <div key={key}>Even-{item}</div>;
    }
    return <div key={key}>Odd-{item}</div>;
  })}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers works. But please note below points

1. Array.map should have a `return`
2. The return element if its to be rendered in DOM should have a `key` (React use this for diffing algorithm)
3. Use `===` wherever possible

So your code will be something like this

```
myList.map((item, key) => {
    if(key % 4 === 0){
      return <div key={key}>
        {item}
      </div>
    } else {
        return <React.Fragment key={key}>{item}</React.Fragment>
    }
})
```

Single liner would be like this:

```
myList.map((item, key) => key % 4 === 0 ? <div key={key}>{item}</div> :  <React.Fragment key={key}>{item}</React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple,

```
  let myArray = myList.map((item, key) => {
    if(key % 4 == 0){
      return (<div>
        {item}
      </div>)
    } else {
       return item
    }
})
```

Here your 4th item will wrapped in div and **myArray** will be your array you want.